# Should we allow unregistered users to answer questions?

Tags: discusión, usuarios, cuentas-de-usuario

I've been a member of the SE for a few months now and I've noticed that usually the worst quality answers come from unregistered users.

There is no point on down-voting since the unregister user won't be bother for their lost reputation.

Sure, we flag them, and eventually the answer will disappear, but shouldn't we avoid all the trouble?

Questions from unregistered users sometimes are good, sometimes are bad, but there is more bad than good coming from unregistered users answers.

Almost every other internet site requires you to register and login to participate or post anything. If you want to make contributions to a community why wouldn't you want to be a member?

Edit: As pointed out by fedorqui "solo el eco me responde" :-) but there's been some discusion about this on META ["Post as guest" is a bad user experience and encourages low quality contributions. Get rid of it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243712/209901)

If you can't comment until you have some reputation, why can you ask and answer?

Comment: It's a good question. it is true that they are a nuisance but the benefit outweighs the cost in my opinion. If you want some more input you should ask this on the stackexchange meta section since it is a cross-site "problem"

Comment: @Joze, I asked because I've not seen the benefit as you said. I've not seen a single question where the accepted answer or one of the top voted comes from an unregistered user. I may be wrong, but I've not seen it yet.

Comment: It happens a lot in general. Maybe we haven't been lucky in SL&U. But it's not just about the answers but also the questions. Some questions come from unregistered users and they are sometimes good questions that contribute a lot.

Comment: Lo que sí puede hacer es proteger aquellas preguntas que reciban demasiadas respuestas de usuarios no registrados. Está detallado en [Protect Questions](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions)

Comment: I think it's all about accountability and tracking, for us registered users there are procedures which hold us accountable for the questions/answers we give plus it helps (or hurts) our ranking, which, in turn, makes us want to be better at it.

Answer (score 2):

Para que no te responda solo el eco...

**En la etapa actual en la que se encuentra el sitio**, donde lo que interesa es construir una base de usuarios suficientemente grande como para poder ofrecer respuestas de calidad al mayor número de preguntas posible, así como construir un repositorio variado de preguntas, lo cierto es que **no nos compensa restringir la participación a usuarios registrados solamente**.

Sí, es cierto que los usuarios no registrados tienden a proporcionar respuestas de menor calidad, y que la mayoría ni siquiera vuelve. Pero de vez en cuando aparece alguno que puede aportar buen contenido y que decide quedarse.

Hoy en día el nivel de tráfico y de respuestas / día tampoco es lo suficientemente alto como para que las respuestas de baja calidad supongan un problema. Cuando el stack crezca lo suficiente como para que esto sea un problema, entonces sí que podríamos plantearnos exigir el registro. De momento no creo que haga falta.

Por decirlo en términos económicos: el ROI esperado por dejar abierta la participación es, de momento, mayor que el coste que nos supone. El día que esto no sea así, habrá que replanteárselo, pero ese día aún no ha llegado.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo. Podemos asumir diez respuestas malas si luego entra una buena, que además puede acabar convirtiéndose en un gran usuario.

Comment: ¿Qué significa ROI?

Comment: ROI: retorno de la inversión, por las siglas en inglés de *return on investment*