# ¿Por qué las respuestas de usuarios no registrados no aparecen en Review?

Tags: soporte, respuestas, colas-de-revisión

Cuando un usuario se registra y escribe su primera respuesta o su primera pregunta o realiza alguna edición siempre vemos tal aporte en la sección de *review/First Posts* y podemos votar, corregir y decidir si el aporte es valioso y cumple con las normas del sitio o no.

Hoy veo [una respuesta nueva](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/22086/1674) a la pregunta [Nos hace sentirnos o Nos hace sentir](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/5350/11102) por un usuario no registrado, pero no veo que aparezca en [*review*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/review) para su revisión.

En alguna otra ocasión había hecho la propuesta (no aceptada) de que [no se aceptaran respuestas de usuarios no registrados](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2473/1674), pero esta situación es más extraña todavía. A los nuevos usuarios registrados les revisamos sus aportes pero los no registrados pasan sin revisión.

¿Es posible que estas respuestas aparezcan también en la sección *review* para que tengan alguna clase de control?

Comment: @walen Que extraño. Yo vi la respuesta cuando tenía 4 o 5 minutos de haberse creado y tu comentario es una hora después. Yo nunca la vi para revisión. Ok, entonces daré esto por cerrado

Comment: Alguna vez que tenía el navegador abierto y he visto publicar una nueva respuesta "al vuelo", me he ido a las _reviews_ y nada. Tras quizá cinco minutos aparecía en la cola de _First posts_, pero no necesariamente en _Late answers_ aunque fuera una respuesta en una pregunta "antigua". A veces el mismo post es _first post_, _late answer_ y _low quality_ a la vez y seguramente si alguien lo revisa en una cola no salga ya en la otras (ni para el mismo usuario revisando ni para otros).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todas las páginas de Stack Exchange están precocinadas y cuando entramos vemos una edición *cacheada*. Esto quiere decir que siempre debe pasar un rato (segundos, minutos, horas) antes de que observemos reacciones del sistema a las acciones de los usuarios.

La respuesta sí pasó por Review, como se puede ver en su [línea de tiempo (*timeline*)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/posts/22086/timeline):

Entró primero la revisión de [first post](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/13581) a las 14:48:24:

[image]

Y luego en [late answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/13582) a las 15:03:26:

[image]

Pero claro, esta información se ve a posteriori, no cuando está aún pendiente: en un momento dado, los usuarios normales no pueden ver si una publicación está en las colas de revisión hasta que no se haya completado (los moderadores sí podemos, la línea de tiempo muestra algo más de información).

A día de hoy las respuestas de usuarios con [reputación máxima de 100](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267080/209901) van a parar a la cola de Late answers cuando se publican [al menos 30 días después](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177553/209901) de la publicación de la pregunta. El sistema es una caja cerrada y no piensa en exceso, por lo que ten la seguridad de que en un momento u otro acabará entrando si se cumplen ambas condiciones :) Lo que no influye es el hecho que un usuario esté registrado o no.

Si, además, la respuesta es muy corta, o [alguien la marca como "no es una respuesta"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190639/209901), seguramente entrará en la cola de Low quality posts a la vez que se creará un *flag* para los moderadores. Si la revisión es determinante (todo el mundo lo ve bien o mal) el flag se limpia y los moderadores no tenemos que hacer nada.

Por tanto, **¿qué puedes hacer si quieres revisar una publicación en concreto?**

- Ve entrando periódicamente en [`/review`](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/review). Yo ya me he acostumbrado a que el número de elementos pendientes nunca aparezca, así que directamente entro de vez en cuando si hay algo nuevo.
- Mira el historial de revisiones de una cola en concreto para ver si alguien revisó algo que a ti se te pasó por alto. Por ejemplo, [la de First Posts](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/history). Esto puedes hacerlo a partir de 2000 puntos de reputación, cuando ganas el privilegio de [Acceder a las herramientas de moderación](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) (¡son una mina!).

---

Aprovecho para comentar que los moderadores últimamente levantamos un poco el pie del accelerador y dejamos pasar más tiempo antes de revisar los elementos de la cola de revisión. Optamos por hacerlo por distintos motivos:

- Nuestro voto es decisivo, por lo que si revisamos algo nadie más lo podrá revisar después.
- Es importante que las tareas de moderación se colegien, para que la comunidad realmente esté moderada entre todos :)

---

Por cierto, buscando respuestas para esta pregunta encontré un recurso muy interesante: [What are the guidelines for reviewing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155538/209901)

Comment: @walen y por lo que veo hace años que el número sale erróneamente: [Wrong posts number on Review section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237873/209901). Es una pena, pues en sitios como el nuestro la diferencia entre 0 y 1 es más importante que entre 234252 y 230825 en SO, pues determina si entramos o no en la sección.